# Send file using bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to write an app which searches for the visible Bluetooth android devices and send a file to each one!

So far i searched the web and found [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) article. In the article it searches for the devices and connects to them as follows: (Note that i logged my other phones Bluetooth address and hard coded it's address in order to test my app)

```
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device);
                if (device.getAddress().equals("4C:A5:6D:00:02:C0")){
                    Thread connect = new ConnectThread(device);
                    connect.run();
                    Log.e("found my phone", "now");
                }
                Log.e("Bluetooth Device", device.getName()+" "+device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        turnBluetoothOn();
    }

    private void turnBluetoothOn() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support bluetooth!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            searchForBluetoothDevices();
        }
    }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            searchForBluetoothDevices();
        }
    }

    private void searchForBluetoothDevices() {
        boolean discovery = mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        if(discovery) {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error in starting discovery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("f68e0858-9097-44bc-9a9c-0c7e342998d5"));
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.e("connected", mmDevice.getName());
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                connectException.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    closeException.printStackTrace();
                }
                return;
            }

            manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket) {
        Thread connected = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        connected.run();
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.e("started", "sharing");
            FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.raw.style);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            int read;
            do {
                try {
                    read = fis.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                    mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            } while (read != 0);
        }

        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me? Any ideas to get it to work? I'm so desperate! I searched everywhere but can't seem to find anything useful on Bluetooth!
Can anyone introduce a sample open source app to use bluetooth?

Comment: try the BluetoothChat sample app that is distributed with most of the SDK samples

Comment: @faljbour can u tell me how?

Comment: you download the app from here http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html, click on the download button on left hand side of the page